# substract mean to image c++ opencv

Tags: c++, mean, opencv3.0

I want to subtract the mean value of an image to this image.
I am using a DFT and then I would like to do some process to see my image clearer. 
I used meanStdDev function but the image doesn't change. What function should I use instead?

> my code

```
    dft(complexI, complexI);            

    split(complexI, planes);                   
    magnitude(planes[0], planes[1], planes[0]);
    Mat magI = planes[0];

    magI += Scalar::all(1);                    
    log(magI, magI);


    magI = magI(Rect(0, 0, magI.cols & -2, magI.rows & -2));

    int cx = magI.cols / 2;
    int cy = magI.rows / 2;

    Mat q0(magI, Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));  
    Mat q1(magI, Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy)); 
    Mat q2(magI, Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));  
    Mat q3(magI, Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy)); 

    Mat tmp;                           
    q0.copyTo(tmp);
    q3.copyTo(q0);
    tmp.copyTo(q3);

    q1.copyTo(tmp);                    
    q2.copyTo(q1);
    tmp.copyTo(q2);
    Mat mean;
    Mat stddev;
    meanStdDev(magI, mean, stddev);
    Mat dst;

    subtract( magI, mean, dst);


    normalize(dst, dst, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);
    namedWindow("spectrum magnitude", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("spectrum magnitude", dst);
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question quite where the problem might be, can you create an [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I add the code. The code is working but there is no difference between the image with and without the mean value.

Comment: You get the mean of an image channel by simply summing all values up and dividing by the number of pixels. And you probably have a third channel, haven't you?

Comment: When I use :
std::cerr << "image chans : " << magI.channels() << std::endl;
It gives me the value 1. So according to this I don't even have 2 channels.

Comment: Guess you wanted to say, that magI has only one channel. This is clear, as [cv::magnitude](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#magnitude) "Calculates the magnitude of 2D vectors.", as written in the docu. It treats your first channel as x coordinates and the second one as y coordinates and then computes the length of these 2D vectors.

Comment: Oh and maybe you should read the documentation about [cv::dft](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#dft), too.

Comment: I am trying to understand it perfectly, hope it will help me. Thanks for your answers LSA